# Postfix : "Connection timed out" on all outbound email

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

```
Aug 25 12:56:20 mail postfix/pickup[375941]: ACF7F200E248: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 25 12:56:20 mail postfix/cleanup[376172]: ACF7F200E248: message-id=<20210825125620.ACF7F200E248@mail.localdomain>
Aug 25 12:56:20 mail postfix/qmgr[375942]: ACF7F200E248: from=<root@mail.localdomain>, size=449, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 25 12:56:20 mail postfix/smtp[377199]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 25 12:56:31 mail postfix/smtp[376174]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.9.27]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 25 12:56:31 mail postfix/smtp[376174]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4025:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 25 12:56:31 mail postfix/smtp[376174]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c1c::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 25 12:56:31 mail postfix/smtp[376174]: E2CD82020B3F: to=<example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=60, delays=0.03/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c1c::1a]:25: N>
Aug 25 12:56:50 mail postfix/smtp[377199]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 25 12:56:50 mail postfix/smtp[377199]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4025:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
```

**I use VPS azure (Centos 8) and, I checked port 25 online but not blocked (Working), And I checked port Using telnet**

```
$ telnet 51.xx.xx.xx 25
output:
220 mail.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure [blocks outbound SMTP on port 25](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity) for most customers.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused whether port 25 is blocked or not